# Is it better to use Asymptote in-document vs compiling separately?

Tags: best-practices, asymptote

I write files with a fair amount of Asymptote in them and I have developed the habit of writing the asy code in a separate file, rendering it as a pdf (usually; sometimes it's a different format), and then using `\includegraphics` to put the image into my tex file.

I know that this can be done inline with `\usepackage{asymptote}` and `\begin{asy}...\end{asy}`, but I stopped doing this after I had to do a 3d-heavy paper. Each time I wanted to compile my tex file, I had to recompile all the images, and that took upwards of 15 minutes at times. I feel like I've since seen a method to recompile tex without recompiling all the Asymptote images, but I don't quite remember it anymore (if anyone can point it out, that'd be fantastic!).

But the main question I had was: Is it considered bad practice to do what I do (compile Asymptote separately, as opposed to putting the Asymptote code inline)?

Comment: To recompile tex without recompiling unchanged images, use [`asypictureB`](https://ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en).

Comment: @CharlesStaats Oh yes—I think that's the one I'd seen; thanks! I still do wonder though: Is there a general preference to use Asymptote in-document?

Comment: @CharlesStaats Can you turn your comment into a response?

Answer (score 3):

You can use latexmk with asymptote.sty to recompile only the pictures that have changed,
using the configuration file latexmkrc or latexmkrc_asydir that ships with asy.

Comment: One limitation of this approach: if you add or remove an image, all the subsequent images will be recompiled. This was one of my primary motivations to create `asypictureB`.

Answer (score 1):

To recompile tex without recompiling unchanged images, you can use [`asypictureB`](https://ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en).

Comment: Interesting. Can you give a minimal example of how to use your package?

Comment: @Charles Staats: from your package "Users are permitted and strongly encouraged to specify a distinct name for each Asymptote image in the file. Distinctly named Asymptote images are not recompiled if their code has not changed since the last latex run.". I suggest taking the time of the first compiling for names, so naturaly they are disctint!

Comment: Assuming you save that information in an auxiliary file, how do you determine later on which image a given name corresponds to? (Assuming that e.g. images have switched order or been inserted in the middle.) Also, having readable image names can make it easier to do things like switch over to an `\includegraphics` model for a publisher who does not support Asymptote.